# Проверить кода на присутствие "магических чисел"

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, инспекция-кода

Делаю задание, для поступление на интернатуру в одну компанию. Суть задания, сделать приложение, которое будет выводить в консоль календарь на месяц в виде таблицы. Нужно использовать возможности `java 8`, работу с датами осуществить при помощи библиотеки "`java.time`". Тех специалист сказал, что в коде присутствуют "магические числа", которые, нужно заменить корректным использованием "`java.time`". Прошу посмотреть и оставить комментарии по улучшению, возможно, допускаю какие-то грубые ошибки. Заранее благодарен всем, кто откликнулся.

```
public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Input input = new Input();

        CalendarInfo calendarInfo = new CalendarInfo(input);

        Output output = new Output(calendarInfo);
        output.printCalendar();

    }
}


public class Input {

    private int numberOfYear;
    private int numberOfMonth;

    public Input() {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of the year:");
        boolean numberForMonth = false;
        this.numberOfYear = enteringValidNumber(scanner, numberForMonth);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of the month:");
        numberForMonth = true;
        this.numberOfMonth = enteringValidNumber(scanner, numberForMonth);

    }

    private int enteringValidNumber(Scanner scanner, boolean numberForMonth) {

        boolean isItCorrectNumber = false;
        final int numberOfMonths = 12;
        int enteredNumber = 0;

        while (!isItCorrectNumber) {

            try {
                enteredNumber = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                if (enteredNumber > 0) {
                    isItCorrectNumber = true;
                    if (numberForMonth) {
                        if (enteredNumber > numberOfMonths) {
                            isItCorrectNumber = false;
                            System.out.println("Enter the number 1-12: ");
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("The number should be > 0");
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("It should be a digit > 0!");
            }
        }
        return enteredNumber;
    }

    public int getNumberOfYear() {
        return numberOfYear;
    }

    public int getNumberOfMonth() {
        return numberOfMonth;
    }
}

public class CalendarInfo {

    private int numberOfFirstDayOfWeekInMonth;
    private int lengthOfSelectedMonth;
    private int currentDate;
    private YearMonth yearMonth;
    private boolean isItCurrentMonth;

    public CalendarInfo(Input input) {

        this.yearMonth = getMonthByNumber(input.getNumberOfYear(), input.getNumberOfMonth());
        this.lengthOfSelectedMonth = yearMonth.lengthOfMonth();
        this.numberOfFirstDayOfWeekInMonth = setNumberOfTheFirstDayOfTheWeekInTheMonth();
        this.currentDate = LocalDate.now().getDayOfMonth();

        if (YearMonth.now().equals(this.yearMonth)) this.isItCurrentMonth = true;

    }

    private int setNumberOfTheFirstDayOfTheWeekInTheMonth() {
        int firstDay = 1;
        return yearMonth.atDay(firstDay).getDayOfWeek().getValue();
    }

    public YearMonth getMonthByNumber(int enteredNumberOfYear ,int enteredNumberOfMonth) {
        return YearMonth.of(enteredNumberOfYear, enteredNumberOfMonth);
    }

    public int getNumberOfFirstDayOfWeekInMonth() {
        return numberOfFirstDayOfWeekInMonth;
    }

    public int getLengthOfSelectedMonth() {
        return lengthOfSelectedMonth;
    }

    public int getCurrentDate() {
        return currentDate;
    }

    public YearMonth getYearMonth() {
        return yearMonth;
    }

    public boolean isItCurrentMonth() {
        return isItCurrentMonth;
    }
}

public class Output {

    private String monthAndYear;
    private int lengthOfTheMonth;
    private int numberOfFirstDayOfWeekInMonth;

    private String currentDate = "";

    private final static int ROWS = 6;
    private final static int COLUMNS = 7;

    private final static String RED = "\u001B[31m";
    private final static String GREEN = "\u001B[32m";
    private final static String BLACK = "\u001B[0m";

    private final String[] daysOfWeek = {"Mon", "Tue", "Wen", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"};

    private final String[][] dates = new String[ROWS][COLUMNS];

    public Output(CalendarInfo calendarInfo) {

        this.monthAndYear = calendarInfo.getYearMonth().toString();
        this.lengthOfTheMonth = calendarInfo.getLengthOfSelectedMonth();
        this.numberOfFirstDayOfWeekInMonth = calendarInfo.getNumberOfFirstDayOfWeekInMonth();

        if (calendarInfo.isItCurrentMonth()) this.currentDate = String.valueOf(calendarInfo.getCurrentDate());
        fillingTheArraysOfDates();
    }

    public void printCalendar() {

        System.out.println("Calendar for " + monthAndYear);

        System.out.println("---------------------------------");

        System.out.print("|");
        IntStream.range(0, daysOfWeek.length).forEach(i -> System.out.print("\t" + daysOfWeek[i]));
        System.out.println("\t|");

        IntStream.range(0, ROWS).forEach(i -> IntStream.range(0, COLUMNS).forEach(y -> printRows(i, y)));

        System.out.println("---------------------------------");

    }

    private void printRows(int i, int y) {

        if (y == 0) System.out.print("|");

        if (dates[i][y] != null) {
            if (currentDate.equals(dates[i][y])) {
                printColorNumber(GREEN, i, y);
            } else {
                if (isWeekend(y)) {
                    printColorNumber(RED, i ,y);
                } else {
                    System.out.print("\t" + dates[i][y]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.print("\t");
        }

        if (y == COLUMNS - 1) System.out.println("\t|");
    }

    private boolean isWeekend(int y) {
        short dayOfTheWeek = 5;
        return y >= dayOfTheWeek;
    }

    private void printColorNumber(String color, int i, int y) {
        System.out.print("\t" + color + dates[i][y] + BLACK);
    }

    private void fillingTheArraysOfDates() {
        for (int i = 0, date = 1; i < ROWS; i++) {
            int firstDatePosition = i > 0 ? 0 : numberOfFirstDayOfWeekInMonth - 1;
            for (int y = firstDatePosition; y < COLUMNS && date <= lengthOfTheMonth; y++, date++) {
                    dates[i][y] = String.valueOf(date);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Странно, но зачем городить велосипед когда есть GregorianCalendar с Java SE 7?

Comment: Реализовано множество методов не участвующих в поставленной задаче. Это входило в задачу или вы сами решили её дополнить?

Comment: Разве в нашем сообществе разрешены заголовки вопросов с применением неделикатной лексики?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov такое словие задания, только java.time

Comment: @GreyGoblin  не совсем вас понял, можно уточнить, про какие методы идет речь ?

Comment: @IlyaTomashenko например у вас реализовано если выбран текущий месяц, то текущий день выделяется. Это условие задачи?

Comment: @GreyGoblin да, нужно отображать текущую дату

Comment: Как минимум, откажитесь от массива названий дней недели и кол-ва месяцев в году. Их можно получить  через API. Также вопрос к цветам. Если мне не изменяет память эти значения получаются средствами java. Метод isWeekend() меняется по аналогии. Вообще много полезной инфы есть здесь: https://habrahabr.ru/post/216431/, и здесь: https://habrahabr.ru/post/274905/